# How to print custom output in terminal - Terraform custom provider

Tags: go, terraform

I am developing Terraform custom provider to my cloud environment. I followed steps to create the resources which are given by terraform document.

```
func InstanceProvider() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
        Description:   "Instance Api's",
        CreateContext: newInstance.Create,
        ReadContext:   newInstance.Read,
        UpdateContext: newInstance.Update,
        DeleteContext: newInstance.Delete,
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "offering_uuid": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Required: true,
            },
            "core": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Optional: true,
            },
            "name": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Optional: true,
            }, 

        },
    }
}
```

The create resource working fine. But I need to print some outputs in the terminal after creating the resource. So that I tried below ways.

```
logs.Info("Getting Api...!")
fmt.Println("Getting Api...!)
```

Using this way, I can see the logs, If I used this TF_LOG="DEBUG"

But I need to print like below output

```
panel_user.my-server: Creation complete after 0s [id=ddd]
Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed
```

This is default output, provided by Terraform. Is there any way to print our own output like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use fmt.Printf to print formatted strings based on your needs: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Printf

Comment: You would need to output to the Terraform logger at the `info` level. You should be able to use the provider SDK v2 to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would look at how others are doing the same thing, save yourself some time and don't reinvent the wheel, the Terraform providers are open source so we can check the code see what they are doing...

Here are couple of examples:

### hashicorp / terraform-provider-aws

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v5.35.0/internal/service/elb/load_balancer.go#L726-L746

```
func resourceLoadBalancerDelete(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
    var diags diag.Diagnostics
    conn := meta.(*conns.AWSClient).ELBConn(ctx)

    log.Printf("[INFO] Deleting ELB Classic Load Balancer: %s", d.Id())
    _, err := conn.DeleteLoadBalancerWithContext(ctx, &elb.DeleteLoadBalancerInput{
        LoadBalancerName: aws.String(d.Id()),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return sdkdiag.AppendErrorf(diags, "deleting ELB Classic Load Balancer (%s): %s", d.Id(), err)
    }

    err = deleteNetworkInterfaces(ctx, meta.(*conns.AWSClient).EC2Conn(ctx), d.Id())

    if err != nil {
        diags = sdkdiag.AppendWarningf(diags, "cleaning up ELB Classic Load Balancer (%s) ENIs: %s", d.Id(), err)
    }

    return diags
}
```

### apparentlymart / terraform-provider-javascript

https://github.com/apparentlymart/terraform-provider-javascript/blob/v0.0.1/internal/provider/drt.go#L28-L42

```
                    ValidateFn: func(source string) tfsdk.Diagnostics {
                        var diags tfsdk.Diagnostics

                        _, err := goja.Compile("", source, true)
                        if err != nil {
                            diags = diags.Append(tfsdk.Diagnostic{
                                Severity: tfsdk.Error,
                                Summary:  "JavaScript Syntax Error",
                                Detail:   err.Error(),
                                Path:     cty.GetAttrPath("source"),
                            })
                        }

                        return diags
                    },
```

---

There are many more out there just pick one you like and follow the same pattern, that will save you a lot of time and headaches ... and of course is not as simple as copy/pasting this code, you need to also be using the same dependencies.